# Converting "for loop" to "while loop" in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to convert the code by replacing for loop with while loop.
This is the code which I want to be converted

Functions for the code in the below snippet. Asked by @Sameer

```
    from random import sample
    def shuffle(s): return sample(s,len(s)) 
    rBase = range(base)
    base  = 2
    side  = base*base
    def pattern(r,c):
        return (base*(r%base)+r//base+c)%side
```

Code in which I have the problem

```
    rows = []
    cols = []
    data = []
    for r in shuffle(rBase):
        for g in shuffle(rBase):
            rows.append(g*base+r)
    for c in shuffle(rBase):
        for g in shuffle(rBase):
            cols.append(g*base+c)
    nums = shuffle(range(1,side+1))
    for r in rows:
        for c in cols:
            data.append(nums[pattern(r,c)])
```

Here is my attempted code

```
rows = []
cols = []
data = []
s = shuffle(rBase)
i,j = 0,0
while i < len(s):
    r = s[i]
    while j < len(s):
        s2 = shuffle(rBase)
        g = s2[i]
        rows.append(g*base+r)
        j+=1
    i += 1
i,j = 0,0
s = shuffle(rBase)
while i < len(s):
    c = s[i]
    while j < len(s):
        s2 = shuffle(rBase)
        g = s2[i]
        cols.append(g*base+c)
        j += 1
    i += 1
nums = shuffle(range(1,side+1))
i,j =0,0
while i < len(rows):
    r = rows[i]
    while j < len(cols):
        c = cols[i]
        data.append(nums[pattern(r,c)])
        j += 1
    i += 1
```

Some part of the code is omitted due to privacy reasons.
Expected output, ie output of for loop snippet is a list with length (base ** 4) containing each number from 1 to base ** 2 exactly base ** 2 times.
For Eg:
if base is 2:
expected output would be like `[3, 2, 1, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 1]`

Actual output is a list of length base with each element is a random number between 1 and base ** 2.(Including base ** 2)
For Eg:
if base is 2:
Actual output is like [1,1] or [2,2] or [3,3] or [4,4]

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Have you tried using list comprehension ? `while` loops are not really a pythonic way of dealing with list of things (even if their use is perfectly legal !)

Comment: @smwhr BTW, at first I had a list comprehension version of it. I changed it to for loop because I wanted the code to be converted to JavaScript which has a C like syntax. Since JS does not have a efficient for each loop or list comprehension for array manipulation, I tried to convert the code from "for loop" to "while loop". Thanks for commenting

Comment: So you goal is to have a more "general" algorithm in _javascript_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable j = 0 should be defined before the inner while loop. Currently, your inner while is running 'len(s)' times only also you are indexing with 'i' in your second loop, you should have used j there.

This Should Work

```
from random import sample

def shuffle(s): return sample(s,len(s)) 
base  = 2
rBase = range(base)
side  = base*base
def pattern(r,c):
    return (base*(r%base)+r//base+c)%side

rows = []
cols = []
data = []
for r in shuffle(rBase):
    for g in shuffle(rBase):
        rows.append(g*base+r)
for c in shuffle(rBase):
    for g in shuffle(rBase):
        cols.append(g*base+c)
print(rows)
print(cols)        
nums = shuffle(range(1,side+1))
for r in rows:
    for c in cols:
        data.append(nums[pattern(r,c)])

print(data)

rows = []
cols = []
data = []
s = shuffle(rBase)
s2 = shuffle(rBase)
i = 0
while i < len(s):
    r = s[i]
    j = 0
    while j < len(s):
        g = s2[j]
        j = j + 1
        rows.append(g*base+r)
    i = i + 1
i = 0
s = shuffle(rBase)
s2 = shuffle(rBase)
while i < len(s):
    c = s[i]
    j = 0
    while j < len(s):
        g = s2[j]
        cols.append(g*base+c)
        j += 1
    i += 1
nums = shuffle(range(1,side+1))    
i =0
while i < len(rows):
    r = rows[i]
    j = 0
    while j < len(cols):
        c = cols[j]
        data.append(nums[pattern(r,c)])
        j += 1
    i += 1
print(rows)
print(cols)
print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you. But I could not understand what you exactly mean. It would be great if you edit my code to the correct code and notify me. Thanks for trying to help me

Comment: @Sreevatsan see my edited answer. I have pointed out your errors and I hope you understood it

Comment: @Sreevatsan I left the last while loop for you, I thought you got the error. I have edited my answer and added last while loop too. See that works or not

Comment: Sorry, but the code you provided does not work. IF possible pls translate this code from list comprehension to while loop

Comment: @Sreevatsan Both the output of 'for loop' and 'while loop' is matching. try to run my edited code, it's working

Comment: Thank you very much.It works perfectly fine now. I should have also noticed. Anyways, thanks a lot

Comment: @Sreevatsan  Please feel free to accept the answer if it does solve the issue

Comment: Oops,forgot to do so. Done now. Thanks